# How to determine which column updates?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have these tables:

```
// users
+----+--------+--------------+------------+---------------------------+
| id |  name  |    phone     | postalcode |           email           |
+----+--------+--------------+------------+---------------------------+
| 1  | john   | 0338294214   | 65462345   | fer.74@gmail.com          |
| 2  | jack   | 0657359930   | 93827424   | jack_m@yahoo.com          |
| 3  | peter  | 0083247242   | 99849422   | mv2003@hotmail.com        |
+----+--------+--------------+------------+---------------------------+

// notifications
+----+---------+---------------+------------+
| id | user_id |    content    | timestamp  |
+----+---------+---------------+------------+
| 1  | 2       | phone updated | 1452642595 |
+----+---------+---------------+------------+
```

Also I have this trigger *AFTER UPDATE* on `users` table::

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `send_notification` AFTER UPDATE ON `users`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  INSERT INTO notification(user_id, content, timestamp)
                    values(new.id, "phone updated", UNIX_TIMESTAMP())
END
//
DELIMITER
```

All I'm trying to do is executing that trigger just when `phone` column updates. (not when `name` or `postalcode` or `email` update). How can I define that condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a trigger, We can use `old` and `new` to reference the values of a column, the value prior to the update, and the new value to be assigned.

Example:

```
  IF NOT ( new.phone <=> old.phone ) THEN
    -- value assigned to phone column changed
  ELSE
    -- value of phone column unchanged
  END IF;
```

The `<=>` (spaceship operator) is a NULL-safe comparison, which returns TRUE or FALSE even when NULL values are compared.

Comment: A small problem, `<=>` means *not equal*. So what's that `NOT` ? I think you have to say: *if old and first value of `phone` column aren't equal then "phone changed".* So I believe you have to remove that `NOT`.

Comment: @stack: **`<=>`** means... "NULL-safe equal. This operator performs an equality comparison like the = operator, but returns 1 rather than NULL if both operands are NULL, and 0 rather than NULL if one operand is NULL."  Reference: [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to)